# How to respond to reminder notifications using the keyboard

Tags: notifications, reminders

I can respond using the mouse, but it feels too slow:

1. move the mouse pointer to the "Options" button
2. click on it
3. select an option

Is there a way to do this with the keyboard?

---

[image]